# getter setter member variable not visible salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

When I bind data with custom controller, the following code works well.

```
public class searchContactCtrl {
    String searchText;

    public String getSearchText(){
        return searchText;
    }

    public void setSearchText(String s ){
        searchText =s;
    }
}
```

but if I changed getter method of "searchText" as below, an error was occured.

```
public class searchContactCtrl {
    public String searchText{get;}
    public void setSearchText(String s ){
        searchText =s;
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Compile Error: member variable not visible for assignment

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define a private setter for the searchText property. E.g.

```
public class searchContactCtrl {
    public String searchText {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public void setSearchText(String s) {
        searchText = s;
    }
}
```

Or you could just remove the `private` modifier and directly set searchText without the `setSearchText` method.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer!!